# How to cache a video in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Is there anyway we can combine cached_video_player 1.0.3 & chewie 0.12.0 ?

I am using chewie to play my video, but I want to cache them so that user need not download the video again and again.

Comment: Check this plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/better_player It's based on Chewie and supports caching

Comment: This package seems good, I would surely try.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using this package [pub.dev/packages/better_player](https://pub.dev/packages/better_player)  which already uses chewie and manages cache  or try following up this https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/flutter/flutter/28094/612075565
Here it uses your video player and cache manager to achieve the result

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to just store the video as a file in the file system when first downloaded. Then you just load the video from the file system and play it if it's already downloaded the next time you want to play the video.

Comment: My app has moded where users can share their multiple videos, So downloading wouldn't be the correct approach. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstopd your problem. I don't know tbh. .